# Regex to capture all text before { character - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex

How would I write a regex to capture all text before the { character but on the same line?

I tried something like the following:

```
pattern = @"(\{)";
regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:0 error:&error];
matches = [regex matchesInString:self options:0 range: searchedRange];
for (NSTextCheckingResult* match in matches) {
    [string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:        [UIColor colorFromHexString:@"#C41A16"] range:[match range]];
}
```

I'm trying to style the following CSS code such that p is colored and a is colored:

```
p {
    color: blue;
}

a {
   color: red;
}
```

Comment: BTW, did you check your previous regex question?

Comment: You don't have to do this, but if you want to make this work with any CSS, you could also refuse matches that begin with `@` (such as `@media` or `@font-face`), and allow for selectors to be on the same line by just looking between `}` and `{` (or beginning of string)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yep just accepted your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How would I write a regex to capture all text before the `{` character but on the same line?

Use

```
pattern = @"(?m)^([^{\r\n]*)\\{";
```

This will only match and capture a part of the line from the start till the first `{` and will match the `{` itself. The `[^{\r\n]` negated character class only matches a character other than `{`, CR and LF.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uY7dW8/1)

To match the text before the `{` only (excluding `{`) you may use a lookahead:

```
pattern = @"(?m)^[^{\r\n]*(?=\\{)";
                          ^^^^^^^
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uY7dW8/2)

And finally, you may also "trim" the match with the help of a lazy `*?` quantifier and the  `*` (zero or more spaces) inside the lookahead:

```
pattern = @"(?m)^[^{\r\n]*?(?= *\\{)";
```

Yet [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/uY7dW8/3)

Comment: I wish I could upvote this twice, Wiktor. I forgot to include that I want to lookahead, but you preemptively answered that question too! Thanks.